# qt sqlite didnt create table

Tags: c++, database, sqlite, qt

i have written a code in qt c++ to make database and insert user input informations .
the code create db but didnt create tables and insert informations .
please look at photos to understand my problem better.
tnx for your helping.

[make db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ig21e.jpg)

[make table 1 and insert data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8EWm.jpg)

[make table 2 and insert data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ze4oO.jpg)

[result : db created but there is no table and data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/164cU.jpg)

Comment: Maybe you should also call your function? Please provide a minimal, compilable example.

Comment: i did it , but dont mention here

Comment: Therefore: provide a minimal, compilable example!

Comment: @AmirhosseinDaghighKia please read [ask], review the [tour] and provide a [mre]

Comment: Handle errors in all those sql query function calls, then you can find where it is failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can user lastError(), to check sql function errors

```
q.exec(".....");
qDebug()<<q.lastError();
```

The function description could be found [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html#lastError)